# How to detect/determine that this parameter ID belongs to this Custom Object

Tags: apex, id, parameters

I have `linkId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');`.
I want to determine wether what object this ID belongs. Is it `Sample1_Object__c` ID or `Sample2_Object__c` ID..

This is a sample debug of an ID:

```
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|a0T9000000KxMLAEA3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the getsObjectType() method:

```
Id i = 'a0T9000000KxMLAEA3';
system.debug(i.getsObjectType());
```

or

```
SObjectType type = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id').getsObjectType();
```

Comment: sir just another question.. How can I determine its Object using visualforce page?..

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo do you have a custom controller or controller extension on the page?

Comment: yes I have. But I'm using this code in vf page. list1Items out is string only.
<apex:repeat value="{!list1Items}" var="item">
<li id="{!item}"><div class="item1">{!item}<!-- apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Event_Booking__c.fields[item].Label}" /--></div></li>
</apex:repeat>

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo and are those strings sobject id values?

Comment: yes they are.  returned like code like this..
return list2 != null ? list2.split(';') : null;

Comment: but thanks anyway to your previous answe. It my need.

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo No problem. It looks like you should be fine to use this in your Visualforce page. If you create a map with the values of list2 as the keys and the object type as the values, you should be able to work with it in your page: `apex:outputLabel value="TypeMap[item]"`