# How to detect in visualforce page if what object it is based on parameter ID

Tags: visualforce, id, parameters

This is the sample link: `https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0X9000000AlE7h`

Is there a ways to know if what object it is in visualforce page?..

Comment: Does your visualforce page use standard/custom controller and/or extension?

Comment: @Bachovski extension

Answer (score 4):

If it's an extension controller that means you already have a standard controller on some object and you've overridden the view page by the looks of it. There is no way you can pass an ID from a different object than the one your standard controller is on. If you're passing other IDs in the URL as an additional parameters e.g. `https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0X9000000AlE7h?myId=a0Z1000000AbCde` then you could get that inside your extension controller:

`Id myId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myId');`

And from the ID you can easily get the object name:

`String objectName = myId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();`

Answer (score 1):

Well probably yes you can. Check the record ID you have "a0X9000000AlE7h" . The first three characters indicate the object type. 
For ex: "https://YourSalesforceInstance/001" will return a list of accounts and 
https://YourSalesforceInstance/003 will return a list of Contacts.

So if you check the first three initials you can probably get the object type.
You can use the folowing cod to get ObjectType from recordID

```
public class SchemaGlobalDescribe{
public static String findObjectNameFromRecordIdPrefix(String recordIdOrPrefix){
    String objectName = '';
    try{
        //Get prefix from record ID
        //This assumes that you have passed at least 3 characters
        String myIdPrefix = String.valueOf(recordIdOrPrefix).substring(0,3);

        //Get schema information
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 

        //Loop through all the sObject types returned by Schema
        for(Schema.SObjectType stype : gd.values()){
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = stype.getDescribe();
            String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
            System.debug('Prefix is ' + prefix);

            //Check if the prefix matches with requested prefix
            if(prefix!=null && prefix.equals(myIdPrefix)){
                objectName = r.getName();
                System.debug('Object Name! ' + objectName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
    }
    return objectName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead on getting the object:

I used:

```
{!$CurrentPage.Name}
```

To get the name of the page.

and make a condition in visualforce page to create

this `{!$ObjectType.[Object].fields[item].Label}`.

Thanks anyway to your answers sirs.

I already get those answers on my previous questions. 
[How to detect/determine that this parameter ID belongs to this Custom Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90035/how-to-detect-determine-that-this-parameter-id-belongs-to-this-custom-object)